# Is there a way to perform numpy.mean for individual components in an array?

Tags: numpy

I would like to find the mean for a list of images. The dimensions of this list of image is (1000, 30, 30). Whenever I numpy.mean this list, I only get a singular value, but I want to find the mean of each image. Is there a way so I can numpy.mean the individual images in the list so it returns (1000, 1), not (1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

a = #your array here

np.mean(a, axis=1)
```

Comment: axis=(1,2) might be better